# matplolib.pyplot axes get the limits over which the data is defined

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Is there something like get_xlim and get_ylim that will return the limits over which the data is defined?

Let us say I do something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(10))
ax.set_xlim(2,4)
```

How can we then recover which range was originally plotted? The reason I need this is because the home button in the NavigationToolbar sometims changes where the home button points to and then I do not get the whole plot when I press it, so I want to manually implement it to show the complete domain (limits) of the data that was plotted.

Comment: You can just use this : `original_lim = len(x);print(original_lim)` before  `ax.set_xlim(2,4)` .

Comment: Yes, that is true. I can save it beforehand. Thanks